# Ajax doesn't work anymore, while it did before without changing anything

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Okay,

I made a "news" site where you can post articles. And you can see them at the news page. I have a flag system, so you can flag it when you need to. When you click the flag button, a javascript confirm pops up asking you if you really want to flag that message. When you click confirm the id variable and article variable gets post to a php script that emails me with a link to delete it and the article.

But it doesn't work anymore after I changed my VPS from Ubunu 16.04 to Debian 8.

It doesn't pass the data to the php script. And I just don't know why.

This is my javascript code:

```
<script>
function Confirm(id){

    if (confirm("Weet je zeker dat je dit bericht wilt vlaggen?")){
        var vid = '#' + id ;

        var bericht = $(vid).html();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "flag.php",
            data: {"bericht": bericht, "id": id },
            success: function () {
                location.href="flag.php";
            }
        });

    }

}

</script>
```

And this is my PHP:

```
<?php

var_dump($_POST);
// this is just to test if the POST is empty or not. (its empty)

$id = $_POST["id"];
$link = "http://h2624478.stratoserver.net/site/News/del.php?    id=".$id."&&secure=S93ja432481Sjefdan23JS23asa923jWISQ128S212g";
$bericht = $_POST["bericht"];


$to = "luuk.wuijster@hotmail.com";
$subject = "Flagged message";
$headers = "From: flag@luukwuijster.eu";

$compleet =  "Bericht: \r\n \r\n " . $bericht . "\r\n \r\n" . $link;

if(!empty($bericht)) {

if (mail($to, $subject, $compleet, $headers)) {
    echo 'Het bericht is geflaged, en word beken.';

} else {

    echo 'Er is wat mis gegaan, probeer opnieuw.';

}

} else {

echo 'error 2';

}

//header('Location: http://h2624478.stratoserver.net/site/News/');

?>
```

If you want to see the site in action:

http://h2624478.stratoserver.net/site/News/

Its all in dutch but you should be able to understand it. (atleast I hope so)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `dataType: 'json'` to your jQuery ajax would solve the problem.

Try modifying the error function in jQuery to this

```
error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
        var msg = '';
        if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
            msg = 'Not connect.\n Verify Network.';
        } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
            msg = 'Requested page not found. [404]';
        } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
            msg = 'Internal Server Error [500].';
        } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
            msg = 'Requested JSON parse failed.';
        } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
            msg = 'Time out error.';
        } else if (exception === 'abort') {
            msg = 'Ajax request aborted.';
        } else {
            msg = 'Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText;
        }
        $('#post').html(msg);
}
```

This functions shall help you to debug the problem.

You may want to send the response in JSON format.

e.g.

```
if (mail($to, $subject, $compleet, $headers)) {
    echo json_encode(array('success'=>true,'msg'=>'Het bericht is geflaged, en word beken.'));
} else {
    echo json_encode(array('success'=>false,'msg'=>'Er is wat mis gegaan, probeer opnieuw.'));
}
```

Comment: It does not solve it. It fails. I added an error option, and it gives the error function when I click the button...

Comment: I think you code it generating a parse error because the response is not JSON. Added more details in the answer.

Comment: Okay, I added that bit of code, and i'm getting a Requested JSON parse failed. error. So, what to do now? It work fine before.

Comment: Instead of the echo statement which you have used.. use the echo statement mentioned in the answer. The response should be in json format instead of plain text.

Comment: Ehmmm, where exactly do I have to do that?

Comment: Inside the if else statement. Edited the answer. Also remove the `var_dump($_POST);` or comment it `//var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: Okay, I did that and I'm now getting an error 2.
So my variables are still empty

Comment: Its working fine.. The problem is you have a redirect in your success method... Comment `location.href="flag.php"` and add `alert('Flag submitted")` instead.

Comment: @LuukWuijster - Welcome :-)